# Phoenix seeding dates

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Can anyone help with what must be a silly mistake I fear. Consider these two snippets:

```
defmodule MosaicApi.Repo.Migrations.CreateCard do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:cards) do
      add :creation_date, :date
```

and

```
defmodule MosaicApi.Card do
  use MosaicApi.Web, :model

  schema "cards" do
    field :creation_date, Ecto.Date
```

I'm trying to seed some data using

```
cards = [
    %Card{
        creation_date: "2014-04-17",
```

I got these simple strings from things I found on the Internet; the alternative seemed to be {"2015", "04", "17"}.

> ** (Ecto.ChangeError) value `"2014-04-17"` for `MosaicApi.Card.creation_date` in `insert` does not match type Ecto.Date

Comment: What about `timestamps`, you can extract `creation_date` from there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
cards = [
  %Card{
    creation_date: %Ecto.Date{year: 2014, month: 4, day: 17},
```

Or:

```
cards = [
  %Card{
    creation_date: Ecto.Date.cast!("2014-04-17"),
```

The generators for the tests were recently changed from the string format (which could be where you got the idea) https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/commit/badf8065d0b025d6b6ad212bfa0b96e897f06a6a

Comment: That seemed to work, but will I have to make this struct each time a date comes in. The client side is Elm which by default produces dates like `1461660831027`

Comment: I've updated a way to use the original string you provided.

Comment: Check out http://michal.muskala.eu/2015/07/30/unix-timestamps-in-elixir.html for timestamps

Comment: I'm getting an error on your second suggestion: `** (SyntaxError) priv/repo/seeds.exs:46: syntax error before: ','`

Comment: @SimonH I had an additional `%` - it is just `Ecto.Date.cast(...)`

Comment: `(Ecto.ChangeError) value {:ok, #Ecto.Date<2014-04-17>}` but I can pattern match that away

Comment: You can use Ecto.Date.cast! instead

Comment: I just did `{yyyy, mm, dd} |> Ecto.Date.cast!` — this handles the `:ok` which gets returned in a tuple if you do not use the bang variant of the method